# Scaling and positioning TikZ figures in equation environments

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, positioning, scaling

I am trying to use TikZ figures as part of an equation, but I am only able make either the positioning or the scaling appear correctly.

For instance, giving my figures the correct size using "resizebox" makes them appear as follows (enlarged for ease of viewing):

[image: example]

If I specify the baseline, then it appears that the resizing is skipped.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\leftribbon}{%
\resizebox{!}{10pt}{
\begin{tikzpicture}%[baseline={($ (current bounding box) - (0,0pt) $)}]
        \node (start) at (0,1) {};
        \node (end) at (1,1) {};
        \node (bottom) at (0.5,0) {};

        \path[color=black, line width=2pt] [out=180, in=-135] (bottom.center) edge (end.west);
        \path[color=white, line width=6pt] [out=-45, in=0] (start.east) edge (bottom.center);
        \path[color=black, line width=2pt] [out=-45, in=0] (start.east) edge (bottom.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
}

\newcommand{\rightribbon}{%
\resizebox{!}{10pt}{
\begin{tikzpicture}%[baseline={($ (current bounding box) - (0,0pt) $)}]
\begin{scope}[xscale=-1]
    \node (start) at (0.3,1) {};
    \node (end) at (0.7,1) {};
    \node (bottom) at (0.5,0) {};

    \path[color=black, line width=2pt] [out=180, in=-135] (bottom.center) edge (end.west);
    \path[color=white, line width=6pt] [out=-45, in=0] (start.east) edge (bottom.center);
    \path[color=black, line width=2pt] [out=-45, in=0] (start.east) edge (bottom.center);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
}

\newcommand{\ribcup}{%
\resizebox{!}{10pt}{
\begin{tikzpicture}%[baseline={($ (current bounding box) - (0,0pt) $)}]
\begin{scope}[xscale=1]
    \node (start) at (-0.5,1) {};
    \node (end) at (0.5,1) {};
    \node (bottom) at (0,0) {};

    \path[color=black, line width=2pt] [out=0, in=-135] (bottom.center) edge (end.west);
    \path[color=black, line width=2pt] [out=-45, in=180] (start.east) edge (bottom.center);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
}

\begin{document}
    \[  \langle \leftribbon \rangle = -A^3\langle\ribcup\rangle \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You code can't compile. The first ` \end{scope}` closes nothing.

Comment: @Altermundus Thanks for catching that, I obviously didn't clean up the code properly before posting it.

Comment: @Raeder, did you try use  a raisebox? `\raisebox{lift}[extend-above-baseline][extend-below-baseline]{text}`. For example: `\raisebox{-2pt}{\leftribbon}`

Comment: No need to use `\raisebox`, `baseline` is enough with the `tikzpicture`.

Comment: The code compiles with `article` but not with `standalone` with the last TL updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer at your question , you need only to use `baseline` like this :

```
\newcommand{\leftribbon}{%
\resizebox{!}{10pt}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
        \node[inner sep=0pt] (start) at (0,1) {};
        \node[inner sep=0pt] (end) at (1,1) {};
        \node[inner sep=0pt] (bottom) at (0.5,0) {};

        \path[color=black, line width=2pt] [out=180, in=-135] (bottom.center) edge (end.west);
        \path[color=white, line width=6pt] [out=-45, in=0] (start.east) edge (bottom.center);
        \path[color=black, line width=2pt] [out=-45, in=0] (start.east) edge (bottom.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
}
```

In your case you need to add `.base` for example like this :

```
\newcommand{\leftribbon}{%
\resizebox{!}{10pt}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline= {($(current bounding box.base)-(-2pt,-2pt)$)}]
        \node[inner sep=0pt] (start) at (0,1) {};
        \node[inner sep=0pt] (end) at (1,1) {};
        \node[inner sep=0pt] (bottom) at (0.5,0) {};

        \path[color=black, line width=2pt] [out=180, in=-135] (bottom.center) edge (end.west);
        \path[color=white, line width=6pt] [out=-45, in=0] (start.east) edge (bottom.center);
        \path[color=black, line width=2pt] [out=-45, in=0] (start.east) edge (bottom.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
}
```

I update your code and I remove the `\resizebox` (I think that it's not necessary here)
Firstly : `coordinate` is better here than `node` if you want than you need to add `inner sep=0pt`. I added some styles to modify the result easily.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{char/.style = { color=black,line width=.6pt}}
\tikzset{effet/.style = { color=white,line width=1.2pt}} 

\newcommand{\leftribbon}[1][1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,scale=#1]
        \coordinate (start) at (0,10pt) ;
        \coordinate (end) at (10pt,10pt) ;
        \coordinate (bottom) at (5pt,0) ;

        \draw[char] [out=180, in=-135] (bottom.center) edge (end.west);
        \draw[effet] [out=-45, in=0] (start.east) edge (bottom.center);
        \draw[char] [out=-45, in=0] (start.east) edge (bottom.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
}%  


\newcommand{\rightribbon}[1][1]{%    
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,scale=#1]  
\begin{scope}[xscale=-1]
    \coordinate (start) at (3pt,10pt);
    \coordinate (end) at (7pt,10pt) ;
    \coordinate (bottom) at (5pt,0);

    \draw[char] [out=180, in=-135] (bottom.center) edge (end.west);
    \draw[effet] [out=-45, in=0] (start.east) edge (bottom.center);
    \draw[char] [out=-45, in=0] (start.east) edge (bottom.center);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}%


\newcommand{\ribcup}[1][1]{%    
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,scale=#1]
    \coordinate (start) at (-5pt,10pt) ;
    \coordinate (end) at (5pt,10pt) ;
    \coordinate (bottom) at (0pt,0pt);

    \path[char] [out=0, in=-135] (bottom.center) edge (end.west);
    \path[char] [out=-45, in=180] (start.east) edge (bottom.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
}%


\begin{document}
     \[
      \langle \leftribbon[.8]\rangle = -A^3   \langle\ribcup[.8]\rangle
    \]  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to add `\resizebox`, now I think it's possible but not necessary.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is `coordinate` better than `node` here?

Comment: First the node is empty and in this case, I prefer to use `coordinate` and here `inner sep` changes the drawing. You can try with an without  `inner sep=0pt`. But if you use `node`with precaution, the result is the same.

Comment: Ah yes, the `inner sep` is indeed important.

Comment: Thanks for you help! With some small modifications, this (making the picture sizes absolute, in terms of pt) solves my problem.